# Compress several subfolders with batch file (win7)

Tags: batch-file, winrar

Here's what im trying to achieve using WinRar and Windows batch file:

I have this folder structure

```
main_folder
- SubDir
- Another_Sub_Dir
- Subdir_2 etc |Note: there are no sub-folders inside sub-folders|

archives_folder
-
```

On batch run I need all sub-folders inside `main_folder` to be compressed and then sub-folders deleted.
The compressed folders should go inside `archives_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command line:

```
"Path to WinRAR program files directory\Rar.exe" m -agYYYY-MM-DD_N -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -mdg -r -s -tl -y "Complete Path to\archives_folder\Backup_" "Complete Path to\main_folder\"
```

This command uses console version `Rar.exe` of **WinRAR** in program files directory of **WinRAR** to **move** all files and subdirectories in `main_folder` to an archive with name `Backup_YYYY-MM-DD_N.rar` in directory `archives_folder`.

`YYYY-MM-DD_N` is year, month and day on archiving extended by an incremental number starting with 1 in case of running the batch file more than once per day.

The archiving is done recursively using best compression using a solid archive with 4096 KB dictionary size with parent directory path `"Complete Path to\main_folder\"` not being archived. The archive file gets the time of the newest file inside the archive.

More details about all the switches used can be found in text file **Rar.txt** in program files directory of **WinRAR**.